# Is there any better way to "grep" from a large file than using `grep` in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

The `$rvsfile` is the path of a file about 200M. I want to count the number of line which has `$userid` in it. But using `grep` in a while loop seems very slowly. So is there any efficient way to do this? Because the `$rvsfile` is very large, I can't read it into memory using `@tmp = <FILEHANDLE>`.

```
while(defined($line = <SRCFILE>))
{
    $line =~ /^([^\t]*)\t/;
    $userid = $1;
    $linenum = `grep '^$userid\$' $rvsfile | wc -l`;
    chomp($linenum);
    print "$userid $linenum\n";
    if($linenum == 0)
    {
        print TARGETFILE "$line";
    }
}
```

And how can I get the part before `\t` in a line without `regex`? For example, the line may like this:

**2013123`\t`something**

How can I get `2013123` without regex?

Comment: Did you know that Perl has its own `grep` function? It's called `grep`.

Comment: @Gabe I mean calling the grep in shell. I know that Perl has its own grep function. But using perl's grep I have to read the content of whole file into an array.

Comment: depending on what and how its being searched, you don't have to read them all into array. By the way, the shell's `grep` is designed to go through files quickly, especially huge files, so you might want to just use grep's capability.

Comment: It's almost never better to call an external program to do anything with data than to do it in perl code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hashes:

```
my %count;
while (<LARGEFILE>) {
    chomp;
    $count{$_}++;
};
# now $count{userid} is the number of occurances 
# of $userid in LARGEFILE
```

Or if you fear using too much memory for the hash (i.e. you're interested in 6 users, and there are 100K more in the large file), do it another way:

```
my %count;
while (<SMALLFILE>) {
    /^(.*?)\t/ and $count{$_} = 0;
};

while (<LARGEFILE>) {
    chomp;
    $count{$_}++ if defined $count{$_};
};
# now $count{userid} is the number of occurances 
# of $userid in LARGEFILE, *if* userid is in SMALLFILE
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are forking a shell on each loop invocation. This is slow. You also read the entire `$rsvfile` once for *every* user. This is too much work.

1. Read `SRCFILE` once and build a list of `@userids`.
2. Read `$rvsfile` once keeping a running count of each user id as you go.

Sketch:

```
my @userids;

while(<SRCFILE>)
{
    push @userids, $1 if /^([^\t]*)\t/;
}

my $regex = join '|', @userids;
my %count;

while (<RSVFILE>)
{
     ++$count{$1} if /^($regex)$/o
}

# %count has everything you need...
```

Comment: If there are many users in the small file, the "|" re might get slow, too. `++$count{$1} if /($general_regex)/ and exists $count{$1}`

Comment: @Dallaylaen: Nope. This is still going to be quicker as you are reading each file once.

Comment: The speedup gained by *reading each file once* is out of question. I'm talking about `/(alice|bob|charles)/` vs `/(\w+)/ and exists ...{$1}`. A hash lookup is O(1), how about very|long|regexp|matches?

Comment: @Dallaylaen: Sorry, I mis-read your original comment, now I see what you were getting at. Personally I'm very happy with the regex, even with many alternatives. YMMV of course.

Comment: @Dallaylaen: A quick benchmark shows your hash based test to be constant time, but the regex time to be related to the number of alternatives (as expected). The regex is _faster_ even with 1,000 alternatives. Again, YMMV.

Comment: @Dallaylaen: Read [this](http://www.regex-engineer.org/slides/perl510_regex.html). All I can say is _wow_.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the location of the first \t using [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) which will be faster. You could then use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) to get the match.

Suggest you [benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $userid = 1246;
my $count = 0;

my $rsvfile = 'sample';

open my $fh, '<', $rsvfile;

while(<$fh>) {
  $count++ if /$userid/;
}

print "$count\n";
```

or even, (and someone correct me if I am wrong, but this don't think this reads the whole file in):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $userid = 1246;

my $rsvfile = 'sample';

open my $fh, '<', $rsvfile;

my $count = grep {/$userid/} <$fh>;

print "$count\n";
```

Comment: I'm quite sure it will attempt to read the entire file in, because with `grep` you are using the filehandle in a list context.

Comment: You should avoid running the RE engine. Instead make use of the `index` function for exact string matches. It'll be faster. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html

Comment: Perl5 doesn't have any lazy lists in general, and `<$fh>` as an argument to `grep` is not special-cased. `<$fh>` will place the entire file on the stack before `grep` even starts doing its job.

Comment: `for (x..y)` is special-cased to not flatten the list. There are also optimisations for `for (@a)` (but not, say, for `for (@a, ())`). Those are the only two examples of lazy lists that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If `<SRCFILE>` is relatively small, you could do it the other way round. Read in the larger file one line at a time, and check each userid per line, keeping a count of each userid using a hash sructure. Something like:

```
my %userids = map {($_, 0)}                # use as hash key with init value of 0
              grep {$_}                    # only return mataches
              map {/^([^\t]+)/} <SRCFILE>; # extract ID

while (defined($line = <LARGEFILE>)) {
    for (keys %userids) {
        ++$userids{$_} if $line =~ /\Q$_\E/; # \Q...\E escapes special chars in $_
    }
}
```

This way, only the smaller data is read repeatedly and the large file is scanned once. You end up with a hash of every userid, and the value is the number of lines it occurred in.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a choice, try it with awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} { for(i in a) { if ($0 ~ i) { print $0} } } ' $SRCFILE $rsvfile
```